# What does Shadow ... directly off ... mean?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I happened to read a line([source](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#abstract)), which made me a hard time understanding:

> More precisely, a local module or package can **shadow** another **hanging directly off** sys.path.

For me it's more readable to add "one that" follows "another":

> [...] can shadow another **one that** hanging directly off sys.path.

Am I correct? If I'm not correct please teach me!

Comment: The "one" is implied. The "that" would simply be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't always need "*one*" after "*another*". It's shortened but grammatically correct. A longer version of this sentence would be:

"More precisely, a local module or package can shadow **another one which is** hanging directly off sys.path."

What the sentence means precisely depends on the source text. It seems that there is a problem with scope based ambiguity of names.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I understand it!